# Java Regex - Search for mathematical opearators and parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split the `string` below:

```
"8-7+5^2"
```

Into the following:

```
["8", "7", "5", "2"]
```

So I am trying to remove all `mathematical operators`. My `regex` is below:

```
expression.split("[+-*/^()]")
```

But I get an error saying that my `regex` has an `illegal character range`. Sorry if its a simple mistake because I'm still learning `regex` at this point.

Comment: `expression.split("[-+*/^()]")`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Can you explain why I have to switch + and - around?

Comment: `-` is the range character.  You're saying you want all the characters between `+` and `*`, which is an illegal range.  You have to put `-` at the beginning or the end of the character class.

Comment: refer . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525024/how-to-split-a-mathematical-expression-on-operators-as-delimiters-while-keeping

Comment: @Teepeemm "*You have to put - at the beginning or the end of the character class"* not quite. We need to either escape `-` with ``\`` or place it somewhere where it can't be treated as range indicator, like at start or end of character class, or right after other range (for instance `[a-c-e]` represents characters `a`,`b`,`c`,`-`,`e`).