# How to Split a logical expression on operators as delimiters, while keeping them in the result?

Tags: java, regex, logical-operators

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525024/how-to-split-a-mathematical-expression-on-operators-as-delimiters-while-keeping) I want to split my logical expression 
`A >= 10 AND B <= 20 OR C in ('3', '4')` 
to `A`, `>=`, `10`, `AND`, `B`, `<=`, `20`, `OR`, `C`, `in`, `('3', '4')`

how can it be done?

I am trying following way(but this doesnt seems to be elegant approach)

```
String orRules[] = inputRule.split(" OR ");
        for (int i = 0; i < orRules.length; i++) {
            String andRules[] = orRules[i].split(" AND ");
            for (int j = 0; j < andRules.length; j++) {

                String[] result = andRules[j].split("(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/])");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

            }
            orRules[i] = String.join(" AND ", andRules);
        }
        output = String.join(" OR ", orRules);
```

Comment: Scan your string character by character maintaining variables such as String currentToken, List<String> tokens, boolean insideBrackets or int bracketDepth. With your basic sample you could also use a regex to extract the tokens, but that will reach its limits when you start nesting brackets

Comment: Updated what i was trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you need is something like this:

```
\(.*\)|[^\s]+
```

You can find an example [here on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/MwRVjf/1/) with explanation.

In Java you have to to match the regex and don't split on it.
With the surrounding brackets `(\(.*\)|[^\s]+)+` you are creating groups, which can be found like in the following example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

...

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ex = "A >= 10 AND B <= 20 OR C in ('3', '4')";
    String regex ="(\\(.*\\)|[^\\s]+)+";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(ex);
    while(m.find()) {
       System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help you out.

Comment: exactly what i need... but how do i split on it?

Comment: String keys[] = inputRule.split("\\(.*\\)|[^\\s]+");

i wrote this it retruns me array but of blank characters